# How do I provide a ddot accent in text using the stix-mathsf font within plain TeX?

Tags: fonts, plain-tex, accents, stix

If I use the font `stix-mathsf` and try to type `H\"o`, then the o will have a large inverted breve accent over it (because the position of the character `\"` is different from most fonts), whereas `H\char"87 o` will not position the accent over the o. Besides kerning, what is the proper way to do this? Using `\ddot` works only in math and positions the dots higher than `\char"87`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The font is a specialized math symbol font, that also provides a set of letters; you can get the dieresis over the `o` with `\accent"87`:

```
\font\stixmathsf=stix-mathsf

\stixmathsf \accent"87 o

\bye
```

Similarly for the other accents.

[image]